# What's the point of running .NET core app over full framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm trying to wrap my head around all the possible variations of .NET frameworks and the ways to use them.

You can easily run your application over full .NET frameworks like this:

```
{
  “version”: “1.0.0-*”,
  “buildOptions”: {
    “emitEntryPoint”: true
  },

  “dependencies”: {
    “Microsoft.NETCore.App”: {
      “type”: “platform”,
      “version”: “1.0.0”
    }
  },

  “frameworks”: {
    “net452"
  }
}
```

But what's the point of doing so? My rough understanding is that by doing so you loose .NET Core interoperability feature (not able to run on Mac or Linux) but on the other hand you can reference not only .NET Core assemblies but good old .NET assemblies too (which is great as many .NET core libraries are still alpha/beta). Am I right about that? Anything else that I miss?

Comment: Should be a good question to ask Microsoft to add to its documentation, as this page might not be enough, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Comment: BTW Whats wrong with your quotation marks?

Comment: @J.Doe, what do you mean?

Comment: @Idsa You are using `0x201C` and `0x201D` and at the end normal `0x22` quotation mark (hex)

Comment: @J.Doe, oh, now I see. I copied it from this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/ So the question goes to msdn :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You also get slightly different behavior. I recently used .NET classic to debug a GetHashCode related issue. [Is there a way to make .NET Core GetHashCode deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183507/is-there-a-way-to-make-net-core-gethashcode-deterministic)